# How to escape a special character from a string

Tags: java, solr, escaping

I am new to `java`. I have an `URL`  like -

```
https://www.example.com/
```

Here I am using this as a key to search in `DB` . Here I am getting some problems , Actually I don't want to encode it . So, The solution is like escape the special characters .To escape these character use the `\` before the character. I am not able to do this ? How can I achieve this ? any help will be great for me.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Specifically **I am getting some problems** is not something we could help with.

Comment: Also, that string doesn't need any escaping in Java, as it's perfectly valid. If you need to escape it for the database to use it, please tag the dbms you're using.

Comment: want to search in the solr.

Answer (score 0):

The SolrJ library (which is the standard library for accessing Solr through Java) has [the `escapeQueryChars` method available in ClientUtils](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/master/solr/solrj/src/java/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/util/ClientUtils.java#L146). Use this method to get an escaped version of a value to use in a query.

```
String s = ClientUtils.escapeQueryChars(url);
```